# android: Button with WRAP_CONTENT doesnt get smaller

Tags: android

In my App i fill a Tableview dynamically and i also add this Button:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int margin = 10;
params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);

View view = new Button(this);
view.setTextSize(textSize);

view.setScaleY(textSize / defaultTextSize);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });

view.setLayoutParams(params);
view.setText("\u2193");
```

then i add it to the `TableRow` which i later add to my `TableLayout`. However, the width does not get smaller. I heard this could be due to the default Background, so i tried adding `view.setBackground(null)` just to  see, what happens, but the distance to the other columns was the same(it was the only row). I also tried to set a `new ColorColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)` and saw, that it even got bigger(in height, matching the height of the row minus the margin). What must i do?

here is an extract of a screenshot. I set the BackgroundColor of the Row to GRAY. the left Button is without changing the Background and the right one with `new ColorColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)`, apart from that(and the text) they are both created with the same code:
[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots of what you're getting?

Comment: yes, have edited my post

Comment: Use TextView instead of Button.. it may help resolve your issue

Comment: hmm i don't really like this solution, but it works